# How to overwrite animate method? matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I want to hand some additional arguments to the animate_all funtion. Therefore, I wrote the new method like this:

```py
def animate_all(index, *fargs):
    print(index)
    all_positions_list = fargs[0]
    vel_list = fargs[1]

    return something
```

However, I have problems calling the method. None of the attempts below worked.

```py
animation_1 = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    animate_all(70, all_positions_list, vel_list),
    interval=200,
    frames=70,
    cache_frame_data=False,
)

animation_1 = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    animate_all(all_positions_list, vel_list),
    interval=200,
    frames=70,
    cache_frame_data=False,
)
```

Frames usually gets passed "automaticly" but not if I extended the function. Does somebody have a solution?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're calling `FuncAnimation` properly. You are passing the called `animate_all(...)` function, when you should just be passing `animate_all` and the fargs to `fargs=`. Take a look at the [examples in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/animation_api.html).

Comment: I read the example docs but what they suggest is to calculate everything prior and then make a global reference to it. A global reference is not a good style in my opinion, so I still want to hand additional information to animate_all(). This is not explained in the docs is it?

Comment: In the docs they suggest using a class if you don't want to have a global figure. You don't have to pre-calculate your data, you can use a generator function to provide data iteratively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use `fargs` with an animation function.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(x_data, *args):
    y_data = x_data ** 2
    colour, style = args
    x.append(x_data)
    y.append(y_data)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    line.set(color=colour, linestyle=style)
    return line,
    
N = 21
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(3, 3))
x, y = [], []
ax.set_xlim(0, N)
ax.set_ylim(0, N ** 2)
line, = ax.plot([], [])

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig=fig, 
    func=animate, 
    frames=N,
    fargs=("red", "--"),
)
anim.save('anim.gif')
```

Which outputs:
[image: Animated gif]